# Does "com." part in iOS app bundle id matter?

Tags: ios

Every bundle id I've seen beings with "com.". Is it significant? Does it really matter if the "com.companyName" is the reverse of my real web domain, like "http://companyname.com", or is it merely a suggestion?

Comment: Using the reverse domain name is a convention to help avoid name conflicts since every bundle id must be unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not significant.

You can name it how you like it, but I suggest to stick to the conventions.

You can read more about the bundle identifier [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html).